# How can I remove character in specific range

Tags: swift

how can i remove character from string with rang.  for example «banana» i want to remove only a from index (1..<3), i don’t want to remove the first and last character if they where «a»

i want from banana to bnna only removed the two midle.

the only thing i can do now is to remove the all “a”.

```
var charr = "a"    
var somfruit = "banana"    
var newString = ""

for i in somfruit{
    if charr.contains(i) {
        continue
    }
   newString.append(i)   
}

print(newString)
```

Comment: Can’t find endIndex.advance in this swift vertion

Comment: There is an updated version as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SWIFT 5 try:

```
var charr = "a"    
var somfruit = "banana"    
var newString = ""

let lower = somfruit.firstIndex(of: charr) + 1
let upper = somfruit.lastIndex(of: charr) - 1
newString = somfruit.replacingOccurrences(of: charr, with: '', option: nil, range: Range(lower, upper)

print(newString)
```

This is simplified. firstIndex and lastIndex returns Int? so you have to check they exist and they are not equals.

Comment: its not working.